# Requirejs text plugin content type of underscore template

Tags: javascript, http, requirejs, underscore.js, content-type

I'm using require.js with the text plugin for my underscore templates. The problem is that the content type of these files will be intepreted as 'application/xml'. So I get warnings by the web browser. How can I change the content type of these files to 'text/plain'?

Cheers,
messy

Comment: what file extension are you using?

Comment: I'm using .tpl as endings

Comment: Perhaps you need to associate tpl extension with text/plain in the mime type definitions of your webserver. That is, if you have control over it.

Comment: Sorry for my late response, but I just forgot about that. Your suggestion was right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better overview I quote the right answer by amenadiel from the comments

> Perhaps you need to associate tpl extension with text/plain in the mime type definitions of your webserver. That is, if you have control over it.